# Elasticsearch query including documents it should exclude and vice versa

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, bodybuilder.js

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** The logic described below appears to be all correct. The root of my issue was actually being caused by the utility we used to push new data to the ES database, not with the query itself. I have accepted the answer that says that the query works as intended.

I have an Elasticsearch server whose mapping looks like this (as output by `curl 'elastic:9200/resourcelibrary/_mapping`):

```
{
    "resourcelibrary": {
        "mappings": {
            "resource": {
                "properties": {
                    "created_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "created_by": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "custom_key": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "defaultAction": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "default_action": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "indexed": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "is_searchable": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "key": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "licenses": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "require_priv": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "source": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        },
                        "fielddata": true
                    },
                    "stat": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "style_def": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "tags": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "uid": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "updated_at": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "updated_by": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the `resourcelibrary` collection completely empty, I add the following documents to it:

```
[
        {
            'type'         : 'video',
            'uid'          : '2c444278-e0d3-497b-9b5b-b70756b0fdc0',
            'key'          : 'test-test',
            'custom_key'   : 'test-test',
            'description'  : 'Random text just to fill up the description. Also, math',
            'privileged'   : [],
            'require_priv' : true,
            'title'        : 'Title!!!',
            'defaultAction': '9dfcdb39-6644-4023-82c3-8227ba184c02',
            'source'       : 'frontline'
        },
        {
            'type'         : 'course',
            'uid'          : '8afb5c95-c7b5-498a-abec-ae829d164964',
            'key'          : 'test-scorm',
            'custom_key'   : 'test-scorm',
            'description'  : 'SCORM!!!',
            'privileged'   : [],
            'require_priv' : true,
            'title'        : 'SCORM!!!',
            'defaultAction': '1302dead-9941-4b90-b35c-30eff4993365',
            'source'       : 'scormcloud'
        },
        {
            'type'         : 'mc',
            'uid'          : '8e66c2fa-6090-49da-91dd-d939124fef90',
            'key'          : 'test-mc',
            'custom_key'   : 'test-mc',
            'description'  : 'MC!!!',
            'require_priv' : false,
            'title'        : 'MC!!!',
            'defaultAction': '7957b8f5-c934-4296-b7bb-70f2cc4b2ad0',
            'source'       : 'edivate'
        },
        {
            'type'         : 'group',
            'uid'          : '80a908c3-dd6c-4902-9f05-647a8af689ac',
            'key'          : 'test-group',
            'custom_key'   : 'test-group',
            'description'  : 'GROUP!!!',
            'require_priv' : false,
            'title'        : 'GROUP!!!',
            'defaultAction': '25b700a5-7563-4d6e-9eab-18465d08a683',
            'source'       : 'two words'
        },
        {
            'type'         : 'video',
            'uid'          : '3d555389-e0d3-497b-9b5b-c81867c10ed1',
            'key'          : 'test-video',
            'custom_key'   : 'test-video',
            'description'  : 'Random text just to fill up the description. Also, science',
            'require_priv' : false,
            'title'        : 'NO-PRIVS-REQUIRED RESOURCE!!!',
            'defaultAction': '9dfcdb39-6644-4023-82c3-8227ba184c02',
            'source'       : 'ets'
        },
        {
            'type'         : 'video',
            'uid'          : 'fbc0f853-9020-4ed7-8d4d-e18ebe75d815',
            'key'          : 'test-test-test',
            'custom_key'   : 'test-test-test',
            'description'  : 'integration testing description',
            'require_priv' : false,
            'title'        : 'Search All Resources Integration Title',
            'defaultAction': '9dfcdb39-6644-4023-82c3-8227ba184c02'
        },
        {
            'type'         : 'file',
            'uid'          : 'cf84e252-1082-4a94-9fe5-45fa73364e2f',
            'key'          : 'test-test-test two',
            'custom_key'   : 'test-test-test two',
            'description'  : 'integration testing description two',
            'require_priv' : false,
            'title'        : 'Search All Resources Integration Title two',
            'defaultAction': '0b7abf9e-c88a-4d19-891d-52fe0b220506'
        },
        {
            'id'           : 'ba462b70-de73-4173-88bf-66bc9d1385b9',
            'type'         : 'course',
            'uid'          : 'scormcloud-course-cf84e252-1082-4a94-9fe5-45fa73364e2f',
            'key'          : 'test-test-test two',
            'custom_key'   : 'test-test-test two',
            'description'  : 'integration testing description two',
            'require_priv' : false,
            'title'        : 'Search All Resources Integration Title two',
            'defaultAction': '0b7abf9e-c88a-4d19-891d-52fe0b220506'
        },
        {
            'id'           : '7f0cbbc6-a1dd-43ca-9108-b31f90904dce',
            'type'         : 'course',
            'uid'          : 'scormcloud-course-7f0cbbc6-a1dd-43ca-9108-b31f90904dce',
            'key'          : 'LD_7f0cbbc6-a1dd-43ca-9108-b31f90904dce',
            'custom_key'   : 'LD_7f0cbbc6-a1dd-43ca-9108-b31f90904dce',
            'description'  : 'This is a LearningDesigner course',
            'require_priv' : false, // Still requires LCR Tooling
            'title'        : 'LearningDesigner Course 1',
            'defaultAction': '1302dead-9941-4b90-b35c-30eff4993365'
        },
        {
            'id'           : '9e195a62-1a53-42c0-8648-4aa35c309d48',
            'type'         : 'course',
            'uid'          : 'scormcloud-course-9e195a62-1a53-42c0-8648-4aa35c309d48',
            'key'          : 'user-SCORM_9e195a62-1a53-42c0-8648-4aa35c309d48',
            'custom_key'   : 'user-SCORM_9e195a62-1a53-42c0-8648-4aa35c309d48',
            'description'  : 'This is a user-uploaded SCORM course',
            'require_priv' : false, // Still requires LCR Tooling
            'title'        : 'User-Uploaded Course 1',
            'defaultAction': '1302dead-9941-4b90-b35c-30eff4993365'
        },
        {
            'id'           : '2b1b2197-48ae-4669-8bfa-7edd440cb027',
            'type'         : 'course',
            'uid'          : 'course-2b1b2197-48ae-4669-8bfa-7edd440cb027',
            'source'       : 'canvas',
            'key'          : '9e195a62-1a53-42c0-8648-4aa35c309d48',
            'custom_key'   : '9e195a62-1a53-42c0-8648-4aa35c309d48',
            'description'  : 'This is a Canvas course',
            'require_priv' : false,
            'title'        : 'Canvas Course 1',
            'defaultAction': '7aef5ef2-e0c1-4188-9e74-3e24057e7e6e'
        },
        {
            'id'           : '5e113295-f905-4a3d-97e0-f5d49926c979',
            'type'         : 'collaborative',
            'uid'          : 'frontline-collaborative-5e113295-f905-4a3d-97e0-f5d49926c979',
            'key'          : '5e113295-f905-4a3d-97e0-f5d49926c979',
            'custom_key'   : '5e113295-f905-4a3d-97e0-f5d49926c979',
            'description'  : 'This is a Collaborative resource',
            'require_priv' : false,
            'title'        : 'Collab Resource 1',
            'defaultAction': 'e153409d-3330-4202-baf2-d602b4cb7d66'
        },
    ]
```

I am working with BodyBuilder.JS to produce a query that returns everything EXCEPT for documents that meets any of the following criteria:

- `type` is equal to "collaborative"
- `source` is equal to "canvas"
- `type` is equal to "course" AND `custom_key` starts with "LD_"
- `type` is equal to "course" AND `custom_key` starts with "user-SCORM_"

In my application, I implemented these exclusive conditions like so (note: `body` is an object created with the `bodybuilder()` function from BodyBuilder.JS):

```
body.notFilter('term', 'type', 'collaborative');
body.notFilter('term', 'source', 'canvas');
body.notFilter('bool', subFilter => {
    subFilter.filter('term', 'type', 'course');
    subFilter.filter('regexp', 'custom_key', 'LD_.*');
    return subFilter;
});
body.notFilter('bool', subFilter => {
    subFilter.filter('term', 'type', 'course');
    subFilter.filter('regexp', 'custom_key', 'user-SCORM_.*');
    return subFilter;
});
```

... And when `body.build()` is called, it produces the following Elasticsearch DSL string:

```
{
  "from": "0",
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "bool": {}
          },
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "collaborative"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "source": "canvas"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "type": "course"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "regexp": {
                      "custom_key": "LD_.*"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "type": "course"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "regexp": {
                      "custom_key": "user-SCORM_.*"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I send this query to my Elasticsearch server, it correctly omits the documents with `type` of "collaborative" and `source` of "canvas". However, it is doing the following incorrect things:

1. search results are **missing** the second document (`uid` value "8afb5c95-c7b5-498a-abec-ae829d164964")
2. search results are **improperly including** documents whose `type` is "course" and whose `custom_key` starts with "LD_"
3. search results are **improperly including** documents whose `type` is "course" and whose `custom_key` starts with "user-SCORM_"

I'm genuinely not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have also tried replacing the `regexp` subclauses with `match` subclauses (e.g. `subFilter.filter('match', 'custom_key', 'LD_*')`,
but I get the exact same results.

I've been staring at this thing for a literal week now, trying hundreds of slightly-different things similar to what is described in this post but this is the closest I've gotten to getting the results I need. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Nick, I don't find any problem with your query. It's working fine for me. I suspect your index creation, the query results of /resourcelibrary/_mapping has a resource element under mappings, whats that? is that the problem. Just check, while I created the index, I have only given the properties element under mappings. Query looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help to solve & analyze your problem locally.

I have created the index:

**PUT /resourcelibrary**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "created_by": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "custom_key": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "defaultAction": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "default_action": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "indexed": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "is_searchable": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "key": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "licenses": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "raw": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "require_priv": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "source": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        },
        "fielddata": true
      },
      "stat": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "style_def": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "thumbnail": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "uid": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "updated_at": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "updated_by": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Data Ingestion:**

POST /resourcelibrary/_doc

```
{
  "custom_key": "5e113295-f905-4a3d-97e0-f5d49926c979",
  "defaultAction": "e153409d-3330-4202-baf2-d602b4cb7d66",
  "description": "This is a Collaborative resource",
  "id": "5e113295-f905-4a3d-97e0-f5d49926c979",
  "key": "5e113295-f905-4a3d-97e0-f5d49926c979",
  "require_priv": false,
  "title": "Collab Resource 1",
  "type": "collaborative",
  "uid": "frontline-collaborative-5e113295-f905-4a3d-97e0-f5d49926c979"
}
```

**Search Query (working fine)**

**GET /resourcelibrary/_search**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "bool": {}
          },
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "type": "collaborative"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "source": "canvas"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "type": "course"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "regexp": {
                      "custom_key": "LD_.*"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "type": "course"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "regexp": {
                      "custom_key": "user-SCORM_.*"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try to create an index with different name &  try to execute these queries. This way you can debug into actual issue.

But the Query is being generated properly.

Comment: The issue was with how the data was being added to ElasticSearch. The utility function was occluding the "custom_key" value from the body. Once I fixed that, the query started working as intended.